# how to declare a function in which we have template variable

Tags: c++, matrix

I meet a serious problem when I was coding my programme. Firstly, I will state my implementation.
I have a Conjugate Gradient Implementation to solve linear system. In my densematrixvector.h, I have two classes, `denseMatrix` and `denseVector`, and I put these two arrays into the function `template < class M, class V > int ConjugateGradient(const M &A, const V &b, V &x, const int &maxstep, const int &eps)`, here, `M` is `denseMatrix`, `V` is `denseVector`.

In function `ConjugateGradient`, I am using a function `void gemv(const double &alpha, const DenseMatrix &A, const DenseVector &x, const double &beta, DenseVector &y)` to solve the linear system.

But this code did not take advantage of the sparsity of the matrix. So I want to modify the code so that it does. In particular, the matrix type passed to the `ConjugateGradient` function represent dense matrix. I want to modify the code to pass it sparse matrix in ccs format. this class transfers information of sparse matrix. So I modify the declaration of function `gemv` like this:

`template <class M, class V >void gemv(const double &alpha, const M &A, const V &x, const double &beta, V &y)`

And the declaration of `matCCS` is `template < class T >class matCCS`.

finally, my computer tells me that `undefined reference to`.

and the code I attach below.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

**mainconjugategradientmethodmatCCS.cc**

```
#include "densematrixvector.h"

#include "ConjugateGradient.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "sparseMatrix.h"

int main(){

  matCOO<double> Acoo;

  readMatrixMarket("small.mtx", Acoo);

  matCCS<double> A; // constuct a CCS matrix

  COOtoCCS(Acoo, A);    // convert the COO matrix Acoo to CCS A

  int m, n;

  m=A.m;

  n=A.n;

  DenseVector x;

  DenseVector b;

  int  nx   = 1;

  double * xt = new double [m*nx];

  for (int i = 0; i < m ;++i) xt[i] =1.;

  x.a= xt;

  x.n = n;

  int  nrhs   = 1;

  double * bt = new double [m*nrhs];

  for (int i = 0; i < m ;++i) bt[i] =0.;  

  b.a = bt;

  b.n = n;

  int nstep = ConjugateGradient(A, b, x, 100, 0.001);

  if (nstep > 0){

  std::cout << "converged in nstep " <<nstep << std::endl;

  std::cout<< " solution is " << x.a[0] << " " << x.a[1] << std::endl;

  }

  else {

    std::cout << "CG could not converge " <<nstep << std::endl;

  }

}
```

**densematrixvector.cc**

```
#include "densematrixvector.h"

#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>

DenseVector::DenseVector():a(0), n(0), owner(false){};

DenseVector::DenseVector(const int & _n):a(new double[_n]), n(_n), owner(true)

{

std::fill(a,a+n, 0.);

};

DenseVector::DenseVector(const DenseVector &in):a(new double[in.n] ), n(in.n), owner(true){

std::copy(in.a, in.a+n, a);

};

DenseVector::~DenseVector(){

if(owner) delete []a;

owner =false;

};



int size(const DenseVector &in){

return in.n;

}

void copy(const DenseVector &x, DenseVector &y){

const int n = size(x);

if (n!=size(y)){ std::cout << " Size error in copy " << __FILE__ <<

__LINE__ << std::endl;}

std::copy(x.a, x.a+n, y.a);

}

double dot(const DenseVector & x, const DenseVector & y){

const int n = size(x);

if (n!=size(y)){ std::cout << " Size error in dot " << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl;}

return ddot_(n, x.a, 1, y.a, 1);

}

void scal(const double& alpha,  DenseVector &x){

dscal_(size(x), alpha,  x.a, 1);

}

void axpy( const double &alpha, const DenseVector & x, DenseVector &y){

const int n = size(x);

if (n!=size(y)){ std::cout << " Size error in axpy " << __FILE__ << 

__LINE__ << std::endl; throw;}

daxpy_(n, alpha, x.a, 1, y.a, 1 );

}

template <class M, class V>

void gemv(const double& alpha, const M &A, const V &x, const double &beta, V &y   )

  int m =A.m;

  int n =A.n;

  int nnz=A.nnz;

  if ((size(x) != n) || (size(y) != m)) { std::cout << " Size error in gemv "` `<< __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl; throw;}

  //dgemv_('N', m,n, alpha, A.a, m, x.a, 1, beta, y.a, 1 );

  for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {

y.a[i]=A.a[i]*x.a[A.lineindex[i]];

  }

}
```

**densematrixvector.h**

```
#ifndef _densematrixvector_

#define _densematrixvector_

...

int size(const DenseVector &in);

void copy(const DenseVector &x, DenseVector &y );

double dot(const DenseVector & x, const DenseVector & y);

void scal(const double& alpha,  DenseVector &x);

void axpy( const double &alpha, const DenseVector & x, DenseVector &y);

//void gemv(const double& alpha, const DenseMatrix  &A, const DenseVector &x, 

const double &beta, DenseVector & y   );

template <class M, class V>

void gemv(const double& alpha, const M &A, const V &x, const double &beta, V &y   );

...

#endif
```

**ConjugateGradient.h**

```
#include <iostream>

template <class M, class V>

int ConjugateGradient(const  M & A, const V& b, V &x, const int & maxstep, const int &eps)

{

int n = size(b);

std::cout << n << std::endl;

//r = b - A x;

V r(b);

gemv(-1., A, x, 1., r);

...
```

The report error is attached below

[report error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tflF.png)

```
[master@localhost part3ddis]$ g++ maintestconjugategradientmatCCS.cc densematrixvector.cc mmio.cc libsuperlu_4.3.a libblas.a -lgfortran
/tmp/ccg7iPUj.o: In function `int ConjugateGradient<DenseMatrix, DenseVector>(DenseMatrix const&, DenseVector const&, DenseVector&, int const&, int const&)':
maintestconjugategradientmatCCS.cc:(.text._Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_[_Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_]+0xb2): undefined reference to `void gemv<DenseMatrix, DenseVector>(double const&, DenseMatrix const&, DenseVector const&, double const&, DenseVector&)'
maintestconjugategradientmatCCS.cc:(.text._Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_[_Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_]+0x208): undefined reference to `void gemv<DenseMatrix, DenseVector>(double const&, DenseMatrix const&, DenseVector const&, double const&, DenseVector&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please format your post properly.

Comment: What is this `compji` identifier?

Comment: now I modified the declaration like this: `template < class M >void gemv(const double &alpha, const M &A, const DenseVector &x, const double &beta, DenseVector &y)` But I got undefined reference to void gemv...

Comment: @Yannlove Your first error was linker error, not compiler error (meaning source code was *more or less* syntactically correct). What error you got now? (It's better to provide exact text, and if it includes line number - specify what that line is).

Comment: now I changed my declaration. I applied template. The declaration is `template < class M, class V >void gemv(const double &alpha, const M &A, const V &x, const double &beta, V &y)`.   error that I got is

`maintestconjugategradientmatCCS.cc:(.text._Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_[_Z17ConjugateGradientI11DenseMatrix11DenseVectorEiRKT_RKT0_RS5_RKiSA_]+0xb2): undefined reference to void gemv<DenseMatrix, DenseVector>(double const&, DenseMatrix const&, DenseVector const&, double const&, DenseVector&)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status `@Abstraction

Comment: @Yannlove That means linker couldn't find definition (body) of said declared function. Where did you place it? Just in case, did you make clean (removed all files previously created by compiler)?

Comment: I have modified it !! @Abstraction

Comment: @Yannlove, use the "Code Sample {}" button in the editor to format your code properly.

Comment: I modified it !!! @EmileCormier

Comment: Please show the exact error message

Comment: I added it just now @n.m.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information, thanks. Post text in the body of the question (not a link).

Comment: I don't have IDE. @n.m.

Comment: Sorry about all the trouble. Please read the answers to the duplicate question.